# How can I test that a program handles partial read()s and write()s correctly?

Tags: testing, posix, system-calls, partial

It's well-known that the `read` and `write` syscalls can operate on fewer bytes than requested. But this is relatively rare and often not tested well. Consider this buggy C program:

```c
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void) {
    const char *buf = "Hello, World!\n";
    size_t count = 14;
    do {
        ssize_t written = write(STDOUT_FILENO, buf, count);
        if(written < 0) return 1;
        /* whoops, forgot to do `buf += written;`! */
        count -= written;
    } while(count);
    return 0;
}
```

Since it forgets to adjust `buf`, if the first `write` were to only write 7 characters, it would end up printing `Hello, Hello,`  instead of `Hello, World!`. It's really unlikely that you'll ever catch this bug in normal testing, though, since it will virtually always write all 14 characters in one call. Is there some way that I can pessimize `read`s and `write`s to do partial writes any time they're allowed while testing, so that these kinds of bugs can be more easily found? A few nice-to-haves:

- Working on existing binaries rather than needing to recompile
- Working on statically-linked/non-libc (e.g., Go) binaries
- Working on more operating systems than just Linux
- Not breaking programs that use `/proc/self/uid_map`, inotify, eventfd, or other special FDs that need to (and are guaranteed to be able to) read or write multiple bytes in one syscall